# Annotations "not applicable to type"

Tags: java

I am quite new to IntelliJ being a Eclipse user for many years, so I really find this error where all annotations expect for the `@Override` are showing error `"not applicable to type"`

E.g the `@PostConstruct` annotation from JBoss Errai is showing this errors all around, where the import is there with no error at all.

How do I fix this?

Update:

E.g

```
@PostConstruct // When hovered with the mouse pointer '@PostContruct' is not applicable to method
public void init() {
}
```

Screenshot:
http://snag.gy/q5cW5.jpg

Comment: Is the correct `@PostConstruct` present in imports ?

Comment: Is your Class a CDI bean?

Comment: @S.D. I have added the screenshot

Comment: Your screenshot does not contain the relevant import statement.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Yah sorry about that but it did show what I meant, as I am not just referring to PostConstruct, also the Templated annotation and other annotations are causing errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the definition, one sees `@Target` mentioning **method**.
So you might have imported a totally different PostConstruct annotation.
*Inspect the imports / go to the definition in IntelliJ.*

```
package javax.annotation;

@Documented
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value=METHOD)
public @interface PostConstruct
```

Comment: I'm sure that the import is 'import javax.annotation.PostConstruct'

Comment: I have a feeling that the IntelliJ error is rooting from a validation its doing with the annotation

Comment: There is an additional requirement: **only one method** can be annotated with this annotation `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: But as you commented, maybe IntelliJ got mixed up. If the init method was already annotated but threw an exception or had a parameter or was not void, then a tooltip with error message was added, and later not cleared.

Comment: Is there a IntelliJ setting I might have missed?

Comment: Not so experienced with the IDEA.